# Parsing the text that sets colors in a bash shell

Tags: linux, git-bash

Could someone either point me to some documentation on the web that would explain how a bash shell would pars the following lines that sets up colors or explain from the parsers view, how the following lines would be read?

- I know that 32 cause dark green to be displayed
- 34 causes dark blue to be displaied

but what is the first \033 used for and what dose the 'm' after the 32 and 33 do?

```
green ="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
```

and eventually export these and other items to PS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start reading for *bash* is the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/), specifically the section *[Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)*.

The characters `\033` (called <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>escape</kbd>) followed by a left square bracket <kbd>[</kbd> is the way 7-bit characters form the [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) control sequence initiator (CSI).  That *starts* a control sequence, which continues until the *final* character (has to be from the range 64-126) which in this case is <kbd>m</kbd>.  The final character is one of the things that determines what type of control sequence it is — this one is the SGR (set graphic rendition).

While most final characters are alphabetic (A-Z or a-z), a few are not.  [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) lists some for instance:

```
CSI Pm `  Character Position Absolute  [column] (default = [row,1])
          (HPA).
CSI Pt; Pl; Pb; Pr $ {
          Selective Erase Rectangular Area (DECSERA), VT400 and up.
            Pt; Pl; Pb; Pr denotes the rectangle.
CSI Ps ' |
          Request Locator Position (DECRQLP).
CSI Pm ' }
          Insert Ps Column(s) (default = 1) (DECIC), VT420 and up.
CSI Pm ' ~
          Delete Ps Column(s) (default = 1) (DECDC), VT420 and up.
```

For your example

```
green ="\[\033[0;32m\]"
```

Taking it apart:

- The `\[` and `\]` tell bash to discount the enclosed characters (do not count them as printable characters with a width).  This is bash-specific.  If you used zsh, there is a [different way](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Changing-Colors) to do the same thing.  Most shells (such as `ksh`) do not provide this feature.
- The `0` in the SGR sequence resets any attribute (such as color) which an SGR sequence might have set.
- The `;` semicolon separates that from the next parameter, which is a particular color.
- ECMA-48 defines 8 foreground and 8 background colors (often referred to as "ANSI colors" although it has been a long time since there was a corresponding ANSI standard).

Comment: Worth adding that aside from the outer `\[\]` wrapping it, the sequence there is not bash specific - it is a terminal sequence. So it tells xterm, konsole, or whatever your terminal emulation program is to change the current color. That's what the SGR thing means - it is a "set graphics rendition" command to the terminal and terminal commands typically start with the `\033`  and end with some letter.